# Symfony error name from js and css

Tags: symfony

When i try to get a .css or a .js like this :

```
{% stylesheets '@TestBundle/Resources/public/css/surveillance.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I get an error js :

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - myurl/css/b5b37ed_surveillance_1.css"
```

Why I have `b5b37ed_surveillance_1.css` and not `surveillance.css` ?

Comment: What the error?

Comment: i have write it in my post, i have : "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - myurl/css/b5b37ed_surveillance_1.css".
And i don't understand why i have  b5b37ed_surveillance_1.css in error js while i get in my steelsheets only surveillance.css.
that modify the name of my .css

Comment: Maybe you can had not install the assets: Try in the console: php bin/console assetic:dump and then  php bin/console assets:install --symlink

Comment: that was assetic:dump, thank you :)